# How to install R Vennerable in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, r, statistics

There are many threads about the topic 2014 but their proposal does not work in R 3.3.1, apparently because the dependencies are not met but I could not install them neither

```
install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Output as root

```
> install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘RBGL’ are not available
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/Vennerable_3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1727552 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

ERROR: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘RBGL’ are not available for package ‘Vennerable’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Vennerable’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp9Ubsk3/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Vennerable", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘Vennerable’ had non-zero exit status

> install.packages("graph")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘graph’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1) 

> install.packages("RBGL")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘RBGL’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5
Package documentation: [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/Vennerable/inst/doc/Venn.pdf?revision=58&root=vennerable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages `graph` and `RBGL` are in the Bioconductor package repository, the following works for me:

```
R> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite(c("graph", "RBGL"))
R> install.packages("reshape")
R> install.packages("Vennerable", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```